# Users permissions for actions based on status

Tags: python, django, permissions

I want to allow users to enter data only when the status is 'inserting'. When the 'save' button has been clicked, there would be time for admin to verify the data, and user cannot change anything. What is the best way to implement such permissions? Is there any place in View, or should I freeze some buttons in the template based on the status while loading the page? I would be nice also to provide some error message to the user, ex. 'Your data has already been saved.'

```
#models.py

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('i', 'inserting'),
    ('w', 'waiting'),
    ('a', 'accepted'),
    ('r', 'rejected'),
)

class Trip(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='i')

class Route(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)
    from = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    to = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)



#views.py

class ListView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'trip.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ListView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't see any difficulties from your description and sounds like you already knew what you want. If the status is `inserting`, you show the button, when status is `saved`, you hide the button and show a message to let user know they cannot edit the data anymore. What's your question?

Comment: @ShangWang I'd prefer to leave the buttons, but when user wants to delete  something or insert an object in the new form I want to redirect him for the error page. In case for hiding buttons (and there are a lot of them in my real-life example) I would need second template and I think that is not a clean solution.

Comment: I don't know what your page looks like, but I would imagine your edit view needs an entry point like to click a button to edit a specific item, right? If that item(sounds like trip in your case) has the status other than `inserting`, instead of showing the button to redirect to a form, you use a `<div>` or something to show a message to let user know that they cannot edit that item. It's a user experience problem, unless you show people some of your work, it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: @ShangWang I would imagine a solution that user with 'inserting' is allowed to GET and POST methods, and without only to GET. Is that possible? Maybe not with a TemplateView?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect solution, but it gets the job done. I had to overwrite delete() for DeleteView and form_valid() for UpdateView and FormView. I hope it would not break anything. Unfortunately, it doesn't provide nice feedback for the user.

```
class DeleteView(edit.DeleteView):

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if status == 'i':
            self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())



class FormView(edit.FormView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if status == 'i':
            data.save()
        return super(FormView, self).form_valid(form)
```